# The 'group' column somehow causes a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '...' at line 1.

I know that it is something wrong with my "group" field, because if I delete it my table gets updated without any problems.

Here is my form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="products_import_confirmation.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
<center><table><br><br>
<td>Prekės pavadinimas:     
<td><input type="text" name="name_p" value="<?php echo $name_p;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $name_pErr;?></span></td>
<tr>
<td>Gamintojas:<td><input type="text" name="brand" value="<?php echo $brand;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $brandErr;?></span></td>
<tr>
<td>Specifikacijos:<td><textarea style="resize:none" name="specs" rows="5" cols="60"><?php echo $specs;?></textarea>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $specsErr;?></span></td>
<tr>
<td>Aprašymas:<td><textarea style="resize:none" name="about" rows="5" cols="60"><?php echo $about;?></textarea>
<tr>
<td>Kategorija:<td><select name="group" value="<?php echo $group;?>">
<option value="">Pasirinkite kategoriją</option>
<option disabled>------------------</option>
<option value="Telefonai">Telefonai</option>
<option value="Planšetės">Planšetės</option>
<option value="Kompiuteriai">Kompiuteriai</option>
</select>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $groupErr;?></span></td>
<td><div><input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file" /></div></td>
<tr>
</center></table>                               
<td><div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></td>
</form>
```

And here is my update to MySQL code:

```
<?php
require("/includes/connection_to_db.php");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

session_start();
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>";

if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == "true"){
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
header("Location: index.php");
}
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) 
    {
        // Temporary file name_p stored on the server
        $tmpname_p = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        // Read the file
        $fp = fopen($tmpname_p, 'r');
        $image = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname_p));
        $image = addslashes($image);
        fclose($fp);

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');
        $V_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']);
        $name_p = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name_p']);
        $group = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['group']);
        $brand = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brand']);
        $specs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['specs']);
        $about = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['about']);
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

        $query = "INSERT INTO prekės (V_ID, name, group, brand, specs, about, image, date)
                VALUES ($V_ID, '$name_p', $group, '$brand', '$specs', '$about', '$image', '$date')";

        if(mysql_query($query))
        {

            echo "Prekė ".$name." sėkmingai įkelta <br>";
            echo "<a href=\"../main.php\">Grįžti</a>";
        }
        else
        {

            echo "Įvyko klaida: ".mysql_error()."<br>";
            echo "<a href=\"../products_import.php\">Grįžti</a>";
            echo $date;
            echo $name_p;
            echo $brand;
            echo $specs;
            echo $about;
            echo $group;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Neužpildyti visi reikalaujami duomenys.";
    }

mysql_close();
?>
```

As you see I made some echo's to check if I get my data and there is everything okay. It's only something bad going with "group" data. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, some `mysql_real_escape_string`, good stuff! Bear in mind it is recommended you move to a supported MySQL library though - this one is no longer maintained. Also, you are echoing raw user input to your HTML page - you should look into XSS, as users likely can run JavaScript in the context of other people's web session at the moment. Short version: if you `echo` stuff to the screen, you should use `htmlentities` to ensure angle brackets cannot be used to add HTML you do not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is a reserved key word and its used it the query.

You need to use backtics for reserved words as

```
`group`
```

Check the list of them here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: `$group` should be quoted as well as its a string

Comment: Yes all the string date must be quoted in single quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day. Just changed the name and now everything is working good.